# ArrayAdapter: сообщение об отсутствии результатов поиска

Tags: android, java

Всем привет. 
Есть текстовое поле с Autocomplete text. Автозаполнение идет из базы данных. Автозаполнение работает правильно. Например, если ввести h, а в базе есть "honda", то появится подсказка "honda". Если ввести и в базе нету - то ничего не появится, а мне нужно, чтобы появилось "нет результатов" и я никак не могу понять, как это сделать.

Вот с таким кодом, подсказка работает, но тут нету проверки результатов и вывода "нет результатов", если данных для вывода нету.
 Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить проверку?

```
    final AutoCompleteTextView SearchCar = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.SearchCar);
String[] cars = SQLite.getAll(); // получаем из базы данных
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,cars);
            SearchCar.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 3):

Ну например надо наследовать свой класс

```
class MyAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {}
```

и в нем перегрузить `onFilterComplete()` и если список пустой добавить в список вручную еще один `String` типа "нет данных" и показать через `AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown()`

это первое что приходит в голову.

Comment: А если использовать TextWatch?Вот такой код отфильтровывает. Проверку я так понимаю надо добавить в  afterTextChanged, но не будет ли он искать букву в слове, а не брать по порядку?
  SearchCar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s); }
     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                       }
              });

Comment: да хз... пробуй, дерзай...

Answer (score 0):

Я вот подумал, а ведь массив для ArrayAdapter формируется из базы данных, поэтому если вводимая в текстовое поле информация не совпадает с информацией в базе, то нужно возвращать строку no result.
Вот функция getAll, которая возвращает данные :

```
 public String[] getAll(){
 Cursor cursor = this.sqliteDBInstance.query(DB_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {NAME}, null, null, null, null, null); 
if(cursor.getCount() >0){
String[] str = new String[cursor.getCount()];
int i = 0;
 while (cursor.moveToNext()){
 str[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NAME));i++}return str;
}
else
{
return new String[] {};
}
}
```